# making mapview work like maps application iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, maps

I have a normal mapView, which can tell the users location, but when users location is located my map doesn't suddenly zoom in to the users location like Apples maps application.

Does anybody know how to implement this feature!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = { 1.0, 1.0 };
    region.span = span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];    
}
```

Make sure your map view's delegate is set.

Comment: do you know how to add this action. When the user taps on a button the application suddenly relocates.

Comment: The method will fire every time the user location changes.  If you only want to zoom in the first time, add a BOOL instance variable called say didZoomToUserLocation and set it to NO initially.  In this method, if didZoomToUserLocation is YES then `return;` else set didZoomToUserLocation to YES and do the zoom.

Comment: do you know any way of adding geocoding (find restaurants near you), iPhone SDK.

Comment: Finding businesses is not currently built into the MapKit framework.  You'll have to use a 3rd party api and integrate those results into the map view.  Look at [Google's Place API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/), [Bing's API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx), [Yahoo's Local API](http://developer.yahoo.com/local/).  You can also look at [these search results](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=site:stackoverflow.com+iphone+map+business+search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1) for more ideas.

Comment: thanks, but do you know how I implement the spanning code under viewDidLoad?

Comment: It probably won't work properly in viewDidLoad.  Try viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.  In viewWillAppear, you might still need to delay it with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay.  The didFinishLoadingMap doesn't always fire so that won't work well either.

Comment: um, I should of said this earlier. There comes up a warning saying "Local declaration of "mapView" hides instance variable. Do you know what exactly it means, because I tried seeing if a declared it wrong but I didn´t so please help me.

Comment: It's warning you that the parameter name ("mapView") in the method has the same name as your class instance variable "mapView" and the parameter variable will take precedence in the code in that method.  So in that method, saying "mapView" by itself points to the parameter coming into the method (which might be a different mapview if you're using multiple mapviews with the same delegate) and not the "mapView" instance variable.

Comment: If you're using only one mapview, it doesn't make a difference.  To remove the warning, either change the name of the parameter in that method from "mapView" to "theMapView" or something like that OR change the name of your instance variable (and change everywhere that you refer to the instance variable).

Comment: I changed it to finderMap but it still says the same warning.

Comment: What method does it give the warning in?  Show the code that gives the warning.

Comment: - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = { 1.0, 1.0 };
    region.span = span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];    
}

Comment: the method I guess is the mapView.

Comment: Didn't you rename your ivar to finderMap?

Comment: If your ivar is still named mapView and the parameter name in the delegate methods is also named mapView, you will get the warning (everything will still work though).  To remove the warning, do one of the two changes suggested on Dec 1.  For example, if you want to keep your ivar as "mapView", then change didUpdateUserLocation as follows:

Comment: Change the method header to: `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation`.  Note that the parameter name was changed from "mapView" to "aMapView".

Comment: Then also change the setRegion line in that method to: `[aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];`

Comment: I changed all of it using the refactor feature in Xcode and everything seems to be changed to finderMap.

Comment: I did it! I didn´t change exactly all of my mapViews to finderMap. lol :)